# CSS transition works on accordion open but does not work on accordion close

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building an accordion component, which should have a transition effect when opened and closed.  The transition works when the accordion opens however the transition does not work on close.

I've tried adding the transition value to other classes on the accordion but haven't had any luck.

Any guidance would be appreciated here.

[Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-cyw8p4?file=/src/Components/Accordion.js)

JavaScript:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import cx from "classnames";

import styles from "./accordion.module.scss";

export const Accordion = ({ bodyText, headerText }) => {
  const accordionRef = useRef(null);

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState("0px");

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSetHeight();
  }, [isOpen]);

  function handleSetHeight() {
    setHeight(isOpen ? `${accordionRef.current.scrollHeight}px` : "0px");
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={cx(styles.accordion, {
        [styles["accordion--active"]]: isOpen,
      })}
    >
      <div className={styles.item}>
        <div
          className={styles.header}
          onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}
        >
          <div>{headerText}</div>
          <div>+</div>
        </div>
        {isOpen && (
          <div
            className={styles.body}
            ref={accordionRef}
            style={{ maxHeight: height }}
          >
            <p>{bodyText}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS

```
@import "../../colors.scss";

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #afafaf;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;

  &--active {
    border: 2px solid $black;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.25rem 0.5rem #515151;
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  }

  &:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
  }

  .item {
    .body {
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
      background-color: $white;
      padding: 0rem 1rem;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-height: 0px;

      p {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: 0rem;
      }
    }

    .header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background-color: $white;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the animation just doesn't have time to complete because the component is unmounted immediately. I don't think my solution is good enough, so you should google something like "react unmount animation".
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-9sq5f2?file=/src/Components/Accordion.js:668-674)

Comment: Interesting, why would the border transition still work as expected?